# Copy and rename a file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access Data Base (Backend). The size is increasing dramatically, and I am sure is because of an attachment field I have in my master table.

I decided to store the file path name and not the file itself;
I found here @Fionnuala, this VBA routine and function that would work perfect for me (I just changed AllowMultiSelect to FALSE).

How do I copy the selected file to a network folder and then rename it with the field ID as part of the name. like  [ID] & “lto.pdf”

ID is a field  in my master table;
The file name after copied would br i.e. **O:/DOCS/678LTO.PDF**

```
Private Sub Command7_Click()

Dim f As Object

Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)

f.AllowMultiSelect = FALSE

If f.Show Then
    For i = 1 To f.SelectedItems.Count
        sFile = Filename(f.SelectedItems(i), sPath)
        MsgBox sPath & "---" & sFile

'Here I need to copy the file to O:\DOCS
'And rename it as [ID] & “lto.pdf” resulting O:\DOCS\328LTO.pdf

    Next
End If

End Sub


Public Function Filename(ByVal strPath As String, sPath) As String
    sPath = Left(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\"))
    Filename = Mid(strPath, InStrRev(strPath, "\") + 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [FileCopy Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/filecopy-statement)

```
'Here I need to copy the file to O:\DOCS
'And rename it as [ID] & “lto.pdf” resulting O:\DOCS\328LTO.pdf
FileCopy f.SelectedItems(i), "O:\DOCS\" & Your[ID] & "LTO.pdf"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that is precisely what I need


FileCopy f.SelectedItems(i), "O:\DOCS\" & Me.ID & "LTO.pdf"